# Render a marker (Simple Marker Symbol) from ArcGIS in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, arcgis-10.0

Using the ArcGIS HTTP API, there are two different types of style a point can have. Either [Picture Marker Symbol](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-map-specification/objects/esriPMS_symbol/) or [Simple Marker Symbol](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-map-specification/objects/esriSMS_symbol/). I can easily render the former using Leaflet and `pointToLayer` adding an `L.icon` with the image provided. How can I do this with a Simple Marker Symbol? I am provided with the symbol type (e.g. square, circle, cross) and the outline and fill colours, along with the size. What is the best way (if any) to get this to render on the map using Leaflet?

```
var map = new L.map(component.find("map").getElement(), {
        zoomControl: true,
        tap: false,
        preferCanvas: true,
        crs: L.CRS.BNG,
        center: [params.centreNorth, params.centreEast],
        zoom: params.centreZoom,
        maxZoom: params.tileMatrixIdentifier.length - 1,
        continuousWorld: false
    });
```

Comment: Have a look at `Leaflet.SvgShapeMarkers` Leaflet plugin: https://github.com/rowanwins/Leaflet.SvgShapeMarkers

Comment: That would be ideal, but unfortunately it doesn't work with preferCanvas set to true, which my map is. Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: I've added my L.map

Comment: But do you require also those special markers to be rendered to the canvas?

Comment: @TomazicM yes I do

Comment: Then I'm afraid you are out of luck with this plugin.